# Does Entity Framework support mapping to an encapsulated Domain Model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn what Entity Framework (EF) can and can't do. Particularly, I'm interested in learning whether or not EF can handle real Domain Models. As an example, consider a few classes that together model a restaurant and some of its business rules and circumstances.

I'll provide a fairly detailed example in order to keep things realistic enough that hopefully the question communicates some design choices that wouldn't just evaporate in a simpler repro.

## Domain Model

First, you have a class that models a restaurant. Here, I'm only showing the public API, since the implementation details ought to be irrelevant, due to encapsulation:

```
public sealed class Restaurant
{
    public Restaurant(int id, string name, MaitreD maitreD)

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public MaitreD MaitreD { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    public override int GetHashCode()
}
```

In reality, this class isn't particularly exciting, since all the interesting stuff happens in the `MaitreD` class (again, I'm only showing (parts of) the public API - I've omitted no properties, but a few side-effect-free methods):

```
public sealed class MaitreD
{
    public MaitreD(
        TimeOfDay opensAt,
        TimeOfDay lastSeating,
        TimeSpan seatingDuration,
        params Table[] tables)

    public MaitreD(
        TimeOfDay opensAt,
        TimeOfDay lastSeating,
        TimeSpan seatingDuration,
        IEnumerable<Table> tables)

    public TimeOfDay OpensAt { get; }
    public TimeOfDay LastSeating { get; }
    public TimeSpan SeatingDuration { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Table> Tables { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    public override int GetHashCode()
}
```

where `TimeOfDay` is a wrapper around `TimeSpan` and in more modern .NET could be replaced by `TimeOnly`. Finally, the `Table` class has this API:

```
public sealed class Table
{
    public static Table Standard(int seats)
    public static Table Communal(int seats)

    public int Capacity { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    public override int GetHashCode()
}
```

Notice that (by design) `Table` has no public constructors.

## Proposed database

One might store such objects' data in SQL server using this database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Restaurants] (
    [Id]               INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]             NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [OpensAt]          TIME           NOT NULL,
    [LastSeating]      TIME           NOT NULL,
    [SeatingDuration]  TIME           NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tables] (
    [Id]               INT            NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [RestaurantId]     INT            NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[Restaurants](Id),
    [Capacity]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [IsCommunal]       BIT            NOT NULL
)
```

Restaurant IDs are externally assigned, so it's not an error that the `[Restaurants].[Id]` column isn't an `IDENTITY` column.

## Question

Is it possible to map that database schema (or something similar) directly to the above Domain Model with EF?

I'm open to suggestions when it comes to the database schema, but not the Domain Model. The Domain Model classes (`Restaurant`, `MaitreD`, and `Table`) *may not* reference EF (due to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)), so adding EF attributes or implementing EF interfaces is not an option.

Likewise, the Domain Model classes should keep their encapsulation, so writable properties ('setters'), default constructors, etc. are out of the question.

On the other hand, it's fair game to use [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating) or other [DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext) APIs to configure the system.

## What I'm not asking about

To be clear, I *do* already know how to scaffold EF over the above database schema so that it generates EF-specific classes for the tables and the derived `DbContext`.

This means that I can, for example, map from the EF classes to my Domain Model like this:

```
public async Task<Restaurants.Restaurant?> GetRestaurant(string name)
{
    using var db = new RestaurantsContext(ConnectionString);
    var dbRestaurant =
        await db.Restaurants.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Name == name);
    if (dbRestaurant == null)
        return null;

    return ToDomainModel(dbRestaurant);
}

private static Restaurants.Restaurant ToDomainModel(Restaurant restaurant)
{
    return new Restaurants.Restaurant(
        restaurant.Id,
        restaurant.Name,
        new MaitreD(
            new TimeOfDay(restaurant.OpensAt),
            new TimeOfDay(restaurant.LastSeating),
            restaurant.SeatingDuration,
            restaurant.Tables.Select(ToDomainModel).ToList()));
}

private static Restaurants.Table ToDomainModel(Table table)
{
    if (table.IsCommunal)
        return Restaurants.Table.Communal(table.Capacity);
    else
        return Restaurants.Table.Standard(table.Capacity);
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out, however, is whether EF can automatically handle the mapping from database data to Domain Model classes (and the other way around).

Comment: EF Core by definition is for mapping **data** model, not *domain* model.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'll be happy to accept that as an answer if you can cite an authoritative source. After all, I'm trying to figure out what EF can and can't do. I have, however, seen and heard sufficiently many people talk about how EF supports DDD that it's not clear to me that this is 'by definition' not in scope.

Comment: Of course you will hear that from DDD people. For some reason they think everything should follow their rules. While in fact they must follow the other library rules when using them. And the truth is that entity data model is different from domain model, has different purpose and rules. Anyway, DDD people speak from their POV, I'm speaking from my experience with EF and EFC, hence I'm considering the question to be highly opinionated. Yes, there are some things that could be mapped, but in general the safer approach is to use separate domain and data models and map between where needed.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm not asking for opinions on whether or not this is a good idea, or *should* be done. I'm asking whether it *can* be done. How is that opinion-based?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. EF-core allows entities with constructors and [read-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#read-only-properties) (requiring private setters though). I think the main concern is that the class model will get overloaded by both data access and domain responsibilities. It's probably OK  for relatively small/simple applications, but when business logic gets more complex it's not uncommon to have multiple domains for various tasks that in the end are based on the same store model.

Comment: @GertArnold How does that square with [vernou's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77040804/126014)? If I try to treat `Restaurant` as a direct entity, EF says `No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Restaurant'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: Cannot bind 'maitreD' in 'Restaurant(int id, string name, MaitreD maitreD)'`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that exact case isn't possible. I tried to respond to " I'm asking whether it *can* be done". So yes, under certain conditions you can apply some DDD principles to an EF class model, but these conditions are stricter than what you want.

Comment: I'd also like to note that if something is a really bad idea, for me that's almost equal to "can't be done". Maybe that's why some responses don't make a crisp distinction between "can be done" or "good idea".

Comment: @MarkSeemann "I'm not asking for opinions on whether or not this is a good idea, or should be done." But if a scenario is not a good idea, doesn't make sense the framework will not support it?

Comment: @IvanStoev Do you have some resources (books, blogs, github, etc.) I can read about how to separate data from the domain model using Entity Framework? Thanks!

Comment: @JamesL FWIW, this question was an attempt to do some research before writing and publishing the article [Do ORMs reduce the need for mapping?](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2023/09/18/do-orms-reduce-the-need-for-mapping). That said, however, the sentence you quote was only to counter the claim that the question is opinionated - which I still don't believe is the case. It's a simple yes/no question.

Comment: @MarkSeemann OK, thank you, I see what you mean now. Great article btw! But I think it's a good moment to take a step back and rethink about the right usage of EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question :

> Is it possible to map that database schema (or something similar) directly to the above Domain Model with EF?

No, EF Core (up to current version, EF 7) can't do this.

The model use initialize navigation property by constructor :

```cs
public sealed class Restaurant
{
    public Restaurant(
        int id,
        string name,
        MaitreD maitreD // Navigation property
    )
}

public sealed class MaitreD
{
    public MaitreD(
        TimeOfDay opensAt,
        TimeOfDay lastSeating,
        TimeSpan seatingDuration,
        IEnumerable<Table> tables //Navigation property
    )
}
```

But EF Core don't support to initialize navigation by constructor. From the documentation :

> [Entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)
>
> EF Core cannot set navigation properties (such as Blog or Posts above) using a constructor.

Comment: [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402182/configuring-a-read-only-navigation-property-as-a-constructor-parameter)

Comment: Please upvote issue [#12078](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12078) if you want this.

Answer (score -1):

EF will not automatically convert the data models to domain models. However, you can use AutoMapper (popular library) for that:
https://automapper.org/

You can define mapping profiles like below to define the mapping logic from data model to domain model and vice versa:

```
using AutoMapper;

public RestaurantProfile : Profile
{
    public RestaurantProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Restaurant, Restaurants.Restaurant>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then you can inject IMapper service from AutoMapper into your class constructor and use as follows:

```
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

public YourClassConstructor(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public async Task<Restaurants.Restaurant?> GetRestaurant(string name)
{
    using var db = new RestaurantsContext(ConnectionString);
    var dbRestaurant =
        await db.Restaurants.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Name == name);
    if (dbRestaurant == null)
        return null;

    return _mapper.Map<Restaurants.Restaurant, DomainModels.Restaurant>(dbRestaurant);
}
```

Comment: If I try to do that, AutoMapper throws this exception: `Ploeh.Samples.Restaurants.Restaurant needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args. Validate your configuration for details. (Parameter 'type')`

Comment: It says in the error message that the `Ploeh.Samples.Restaurants.Restaurant` class should have a constructor without any arguments. You can add another empty constructor to that class to fix that issue.

Comment: Indeed, and per the OP, that's an absolute no-go.

Comment: To be fair, I _think_ the ctor may be private. But I'm with you, @MarkSeemann